# using multiple (different) cells in UITableView

Tags: ios

I am trying to implement a tableView setup where I show multiple cells with different stuff in it one after the other. The code I am using is

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"ScribbleCell";
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier2 = @"ScribbleCell2";
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier3 = @"ScribbleCell3";
    UITableViewCell *cell = nil;
    //UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone; // or you have the previous 'None' style...
    self.tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    if (indexPath.row % 3 == 0) {
        // this is a content cell
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

        if (cell == nil){
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
        }

        // get the model index
        NSInteger indexInModel = indexPath.row / 3;

        NSDictionary *scribble = [scribbles objectAtIndex:indexInModel];
        cell.textLabel.text = scribbles[@"name"];
    }
    else if(indexPath.row % 2 == 0) {
        // red color
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier2];

        if(cell == nil)
        {
            cell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ScribbleCell2" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
        }
    }else{
        // green color
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier3];

        if(cell == nil)
        {
            cell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ScribbleCell3" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
        }
    }

    return cell;
}
```

the ideal order should be, the name then red and then green, but that doesn't seem to be the case. The order seems to be random and changes as I scroll down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try this

```
if (indexPath.row % 3 == 0) {
    // first cell code
}
else if (indexPath.row % 3 == 1) {
    // second cell code
}
else {
    // third cell code
}
```

Edit for 5 different cells:

```
if (indexPath.row % 5 == 0) {
    // first cell code
}
else if (indexPath.row % 5 == 1) {
    // second cell code
}
else if (indexPath.row % 5 == 2) {
    // third cell code
}
else if (indexPath.row % 5 == 3) {
    // fourth cell code
}
else {
    // fifth cell code
}
```

Also you need to make sure that each record has 5 cells, to do so you need to tell the UITableView that you have CellsCount = N Records X 5 Cells per record see the following snippet.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
     return [myRecords count] * 5;
}
```

Comment: :) yes Mahmoud thats exactly what I ended up implementing,

Comment: Mahmoud, this doesnt seem to work. its skipping my data. There are supposed to be 90 posts, its posting only 23